# cannot use baseURL (type *url.URL) as type string in argument to http.Get

Tags: go, webserver

I wrote a simple web server that appends some relative path to the base URL using url.ResolveReference. And then I want to get the content of resultant URL using http.Get() but the problem is that http.get() take string as the argument and I have an object of type *url.URL.How can I resolve this problem?

My code is given bellow:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "net/url"
)

func factHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    str1 := "http://www.meaningfultype.com/"
    u1, _ := url.Parse(str1)
    str2 := "/clarendon.html"
    u2, _ := url.Parse(str2)
    u3 := u1.ResolveReference(u2)
    fmt.Println("url:", u3)
    res, err := http.Get(u3)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    robots, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)

    res.Body.Close()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    contentType := res.Header.Get("Content-Type")
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", contentType)
    w.Write(robots)
}
```

Comment: `URL` has a `String()` method that does that.

Answer (score 2):

Call the `String()` method of u3 and pass the returned string to `http.Get()`:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "net/url"
)

func factHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    str1 := "http://www.meaningfultype.com/"
    u1, _ := url.Parse(str1)
    str2 := "/clarendon.html"
    u2, _ := url.Parse(str2)
    u3 := u1.ResolveReference(u2)
    fmt.Println("url:", u3)
    res, err := http.Get(u3.String())         // Change this line
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    robots, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)

    res.Body.Close()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    contentType := res.Header.Get("Content-Type")
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", contentType)
    w.Write(robots)
}
```